# How to store result of a Future for later use

Tags: dart

Suppose our goal is to build a `List` which we will call `storedResult`.

We have a `Future<List>` returning function called multiple times:

```dart
Future<List> getList()...
```

Suppose that we will call our `getList()` function for the unknown multiple times and want to store the result of each `List` into our `storedResult`:

```dart
List storedResult = [];

someOtherList.forEach((element)){
    getList().then((resultingList)){
        storedResult.addAll(resultingList);
    }
}

print(storedResult);
```

If we run this code, it will print as `[]`.  How do we express this so that the result is rather:

```
[resultingList, resultingList, ..., ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that Futures return immediately, but their associated callbacks run asynchronously. Specifically, the work that `getList()` does (and everything that `then` does) do not happen until execution returns to the event loop.

Your problem is that you're trying to print the result of an asynchronous operation synchronously, and that won't work.

If you want to use the stored result, then what you should do is something like:

```dart
Future<List<List>> globFutures(List someOtherList) {
  List<Future> futures = [];
  someOtherList.forEach((element) {
    futures.add(getList());
  });

  // Automatically completes to a List containing all the
  // results of all of the futures.
  return Future.wait(futures);
}

main() {
  var storedResults = [];

  globFutures(someOtherList)
    .then((List<List> results) {
      storedResults = results;

      // Run code in here that depends on storedResults being available.
      print(storedResults);
    });

  // Do **NOT** use storedResults here, as it will be [].
  // The Future functions have not yet run!
  assert(storedResults == []);
};
```